# datetime with timezone field/template output strange behavior

Tags: python, django, datetime, timestamp-with-timezone, django-timezone

Timezone settings settings.py:

```
USE_TZ = True
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow' # +4
```

Record in database table(postgresql 9.1, timestamp with timezone :

> 2012-12-19 15:30:51.164368+04

Django date filter:

```
date(object.date,"d.m.Y H:i:s"),
```

And after all this manipulations datetime filed output in template as :

> 19.12.2012 11:30:51

Why this happens? Why django don't use TZ information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `USE_TZ` is `False`, this is the time zone in which Django will store all datetimes. When `USE_TZ` is `True`, this is the default time zone that Django will use to display datetimes in templates and to interpret datetimes entered in forms.

Check this document, [Django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#time-zone)